# My peer's stream doesn't appear, what am I doing wrong? [WebRTC]

Tags: javascript, async-await, webrtc

I'm trying to receive my partner's stream but it's not working, I don't know if I'm misimplementing the example given by WebRTC website and I can't understand it well because I'm new to this.

That I have to do?

```
const connection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] });


async function start() {

const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});

localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    connection.addTrack(track, localStream);
});

    }
    
    
    const remoteVideo = document.querySelector('.remote-video');

connection.addEventListener('track', async (event) => {
    const remoteStream = event.streams[0];
    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
    
    connection.addTrack(event.track);
    
});
```

Comment: connecting to another peer is not that obvious. after all the peer needs to agree and send you its address and other things related to protocol. however, to facilitate this initial negotiation you need a server. so your implemented the example incompletely.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try This:-

```
const start = async () => {try {
const constraints = { video: { cursor: "always" }, audio: false };
const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(
  constraints
);

screenStream = localStream;
let videoTrack = screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0];

return localStream;
} catch (error) {}}


const remoteVideo = document.querySelector('.remote-video')

 function handleRemoteStreamAddedScreen(event) {
alert("Remote stream added.")
if ("srcObject" in remoteVideo) {
 remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0]
} else {
 remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream)}

remoteScreenStream = event.stream}
```

I hope it will be work for you.